# Delphi interface not reference counted

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Reading the Expert Delphi book I have found something that I cannot understand. The author has created an unit with this code:

```
 IToDoData = interface //CRUD
    function ToDoCreate(aValue: TToDo): integer;
    function ToDoRead(id: integer; out aValue: TToDo): boolean;
    function ToDoUpdate(aValue: TToDo): boolean;
    function ToDoDelete(id: integer): boolean;
    procedure ToDoList(aList: TToDos);
  end;
```

Then he decided to use a `DataModule` and implement the above interface in this way:

```
type
  TDMToDo = class(TDataModule, IToDoData)
    // ... other code ...
  public
    // IToDoData
    function ToDoCreate(aValue: TToDo): integer;
    function ToDoRead(id: integer; out aValue: TToDo): boolean;
    function ToDoUpdate(aValue: TToDo): boolean;
    function ToDoDelete(id: integer): boolean;
    procedure ToDoList(aList: TToDos);
  end;
```

So far so good but note that he **didn't** put `TInterfacedObject` so here we haven't methods like AddRef and so on. My guess is that the above code is fine but it has to be included inside the try ... finally block.

In the main form (the data module unit is the uses clauses of course) there is a function like this:

```
function TFormToDo.GetToDoData: IToDoData;
begin
  if DMToDo = nil then
    DMToDo := TDMToDo.Create(Application);
  Result := DMToDo;
end;
```

The code above allows to write code like this:

```
begin
  GetToDoData.ToDoList(FToDos);

  ListView1.BeginUpdate;
  try
    //populate the list
  finally
    ListView1.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Doesn't this produce a memory leak? At least on windows. I am new to delphi so I might fail but I have read online that Android and IOs has ARC so no need to worry about try finally.

Windows does NOT have ARC so I have to use the try .. finally unless there is an implementation like TInterfacedObject (here there isn't). So is that a mistake?

---

The app is about a ToDo app in which you write/read/save your notes. The data module has FireDAC access components and the interface methods are used to access the db. This is to keep a separation between UI and db stuff.

Comment: It will. What else to say, it's a horrible weather in Madrid :)

Comment: @Victoria same here sadly ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`TDataModule` is `TComponent` descendant, and `TComponent` implements `IInterface` and related reference counting methods

```
  TComponent = class(TPersistent, IInterface, IInterfaceComponentReference)
```

However, `TComponent` has reference counting disabled and components are managed either manually or through ownership model on non-ARC compiler.

To be more precise, `TComponent` has disabled reference counting unless it serves as wrapper for Windows COM object. Which is not the case here.

On ARC compiler there is slight complication with manual management - actually automatic management, because if you don't allow `TComponent` descendants to be managed through ownership, they have to be released with `DisposeOf`.

`TComponent` behavior is different than `TInterfacedObject` behavior regarding reference counting on classic compiler.

In above case, there is no leak because `Application` owns that data module and it will manage data module lifetime appropriately on all compilers.

---

`try... finally` block is there not for memory management, but to protect `BeginUpdate... EndUpdate` You have to leave `try...finally` on all compilers.

Comment: So adding the TInterfacedObject would be a mistake or just something extra?

Comment: Where would you put `TInterfacedObject`? You can only inherit from one class, and that is `TDataModule` here.

Comment: Ok thank you :) so the data module is already giving me what I need to be sure that It will be ref counted

Comment: It will not be ref counted on non-ARC compiler. TComponent disables reference counting. It has different behavior than TInterfacedObject.